# link error while porting to vs2005

Tags: visual-c++

I am getting the following link error, as it says it is already defined in other library,
and I have set the same settings for my libraries which are linked to this,

I used standard windows library and multi threaded option

msvcprt.lib(MSVCP80.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: char const * __thiscall std::basic_string,class std::allocator >::c_str(void)const " (?c_str@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QBEPBDXZ) already defined in prot.lb

Comment: Next time, please do at least basic spell checking when asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this is your issue:

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;q148652